# LINQ: How to get parent types' properties while getting their children collections

Tags: c#, linq

---

### I have a collection of parent types that contains a list of children types:

---

```
public class ParentType
{

    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public List<ChildType> ChildTypes { get; set; }

}

public class ChildType
{

    public int ID;
    public string Name;

}
```

---

### I need to use LINQ to turn them into a collection of the following type:

---

```
public class MixedType
{

    public int ParentID;
    public string ParentName;
    public int ChildID;
    public string ChildName;

}
```

---

### I've already tried (select many) but could not get the ParentType properties.

Comment: Are you using linq to sql or entity framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from p in parents
from c in p.Children
select new MixedType(...)
```

Should work.

Answer (score 6):

Provided I understand what you are going to do, you have to use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631.aspx) of [SelectManay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) extension which allows you to invoke a *result selector* function on each element therein.

The query should be:

```
var lst = new List<ParentType>();

var query = lst.SelectMany(p => p.ChildTypes, 
                                (parent, child) => new { parent, child }
                          )
               .Select(p => new MixedType
                            {
                                ChildID = p.child.ID,
                                ChildName = p.child.Name,
                                ParentID = p.parent.ID,
                                ParentName = p.parent.Name
                            });
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to project a collection of MixedType out of one instance of ParentType

```
var parent = new ParentType();

var mixedList = parent.ChildTypes
                  .Select(c => new MixedType
                  {
                     ParentID = parent.ID,
                     ParentName = parent.Name,
                     ChildID = c.ID,
                     ChildName = c.Name

                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could try something like this:

```
var mixed = 
    from child in parent.ChildTypes 
    select new MixedType 
    { 
        ParentID = parent.ID,
        ParentName = parent.Name,
        ChildID = child.ID, 
        ChildName = child.Name
    };
```

Comment: That would work in case I have one parent.. I wasn't clear in my question so I modified it to declare that I have a collection of parent types ...